# Circle doesnt stay on screen after mouse click. Using GLFW

Tags: c++, glfw

Am trying to make a ticTactoe game using OpenGL and am having some issue with the draw circle on click part. When i click and hold LMB the circle is drawn but as soon as i let go it disappears.

I believe the reason is because of glfwSwapBuffers, but i cant seem to find a way to make the on click circle stay even when more are drawn.

Vertex and Fragment Shader

```
const char* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
"}\0";
const char* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"uniform vec3 color;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";
```

Circle Function

```
void buildCircle(float radius, int vCount,float pointX,float pointY)
{
    float angle = 360.0f / vCount;

    int triangleCount = vCount - 2;

    std::vector<glm::vec3> temp;
    // positions
    for (int i = 0; i < vCount; i++)
    {
        float currentAngle = angle * i;
        float x = pointX + radius * cos(glm::radians(currentAngle));
        float y = pointY + radius * sin(glm::radians(currentAngle));
        float z =  0.0f;

        vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(x, y, z));
    }

    // push indexes of each triangle points
    for (int i = 0; i < triangleCount; i++)
    {
        indices.push_back(0);
        indices.push_back(i + 1);
        indices.push_back(i + 2);
    }

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glGenBuffers(1, &elementBuffer);

    glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * vertices.size(), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * indices.size(), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

}
```

Mouse Callback

```
bool flag1 = false;
double x = 0, y = 0;
double xpos, ypos = 0;
void mouse_button(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)
{
    if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        xpos, ypos;
        glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);
        //char out[256];
        //snprintf(out, sizeof(out), "%G , %G \n", xpos, ypos);
        //OutputDebugStringA(out);
        //Converting window coordinates to openGL coords
        int width, height;
        glfwGetWindowSize(window, &width, &height);
        x = (xpos / width) * 2 - 1;
        y = (1 - ypos / height) * 2 - 1;
        char out2[256];
        snprintf(out2, sizeof(out2), "%G , %G \n", x, y);
        OutputDebugStringA(out2);
        cout << "helloworld" << endl;
        flag1 = true;
        buildCircle(0.1, 15, x, y);
    }
}
```

Lines Struct and function

```
typedef struct vec2 {
    float x;
    float y;
} vec2;

vec2* vec2_init(float _x, float _y) {
    vec2* v = (vec2*)malloc(sizeof(vec2));
    v->x = _x;
    v->y = _y;
    return v;
}

typedef struct vec3 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} vec3;

vec3* vec3_init(float _x, float _y, float _z) {
    vec3* v = (vec3*)malloc(sizeof(vec3));
    v->x = _x;
    v->y = _y;
    v->z = _z;
    return v;
}

typedef struct line {
    int shaderProgram;
    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    float* vertices;
    vec2* startPoint;
    vec2* endPoint;
    vec3* lineColor;
} line;

line* line_init(vec2* start, vec2* end) {

    line* l = (line*)malloc(sizeof(line));

    float x1 = start->x;
    float y1 = start->y;
    float x2 = end->x;
    float y2 = end->y;


    // convert 3d world space position 2d screen space position
    //x1 = 2 * x1 / w - 1;
    //y1 = 2 * y1 / h - 1;

    //x2 = 2 * x2 / w - 1;
    //y2 = 2 * y2 / h - 1;

    start->x = x1;
    start->y = y1;
    end->x = x2;
    end->y = y2;

    l->startPoint = start;
    l->endPoint = end;
    l->lineColor = vec3_init(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    // vertex shader
    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // fragment shader
    int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // link shaders
    l->shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(l->shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(l->shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(l->shaderProgram);

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    // setting vertex data
    l->vertices = (float*)(malloc(sizeof(float) * 6));
    l->vertices[0] = start->x;
    l->vertices[1] = start->y;
    l->vertices[2] = end->x;
    l->vertices[3] = end->y;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &l->VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &l->VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(l->VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, l->VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(l->vertices) * 4,
        &l->vertices[0],
        GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
        2 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    return l;
}


int line_draw(line* l) {

    glUseProgram(l->shaderProgram);
    //glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(l->shaderProgram, "color"),
    //    1, &l->lineColor->x);

    glBindVertexArray(l->VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Main

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // initialize GLFW
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // create a window pointer
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Hello Circle", NULL, NULL);
    // error check
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error. I could not create a window at all!" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouse_button);
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_MOUSE_BUTTONS, GLFW_TRUE);

    //buildCircle(0.1,4);


    // vertex shader
    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // fragment shader
    int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    int shaderProg = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProg, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProg, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProg);



   while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwWaitEvents();
        glClearColor(255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        line* line7 = line_init(vec2_init(0.7, 0.4), vec2_init(-0.7, 0.4));
        line* line8 = line_init(vec2_init(0.3, 0.8), vec2_init(0.3, -0.8));
        line* line9 = line_init(vec2_init(-0.3, 0.8), vec2_init(-0.3, -0.8));
        line* line10 = line_init(vec2_init(-0.7, -0.4), vec2_init(0.7, -0.4));
        line_draw(line7);
        line_draw(line8);
        line_draw(line9);
        line_draw(line10);



        glUseProgram(shaderProg);

        glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);

    


        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
        if (flag1 == true) {
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
            cout << "draw1" << endl;

            //glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);
            //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
            //glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * vertices.size(),NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW); 
            
          /*  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuffer);
            glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * indices.size(), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);*/

            vertices.clear();
            indices.clear();
            flag1 = false;
        }


        //glfwWaitEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        
        //glfwPollEvents();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you keep the state of the board? I would expect your mouse handler to update the board state (if needed/allowed) and your main loop to just draw circles based on the contents of the board.

Comment: Havent coded any game logic or state manager yet, just trying to get all the draw functions for the board, X and circle to work then move on to when , where and if they can be drawn.

Comment: Well, you need that. OpenGL applications typically clear the screen every frame and render a new frame from scratch.

Comment: How would you say i go about doing that? any hint that could point me in the right direction for it?

Comment: 1) Decide on a data structure for representing your game state 2) Add code to `main` to define an instance of it 3) Add code to the loop in `main` to render non-empty spaces in your game state as circles 4) update `mouse_button` to change the state.